# get data from second table by using data in first table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

there are two tables

Table 1 − `CUSTOMERS` Table

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  32 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  25 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  27 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Table 2 − `ORDERS` Table

```
+-----+---------------------+------
|OID  | Age| CUSTOMER_ID | AMOUNT |
+-----+---------------------+------
| 102 | 22 |           3 |   3000 |
| 100 | 32 |           3 |   1500 |
| 101 | 25 |           2 |   1560 |
| 103 | 27 |           4 |   2060 |
+-----+---------------------+------
```

the query should print all the data from first table and in place of `AGE` it should print `OID`

ex:

input `ID`:3

output:

```
ID  NAME     OID  ADDRESS   SALARY 
3  kaushik   100  Kota       2000.00
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't add tags for products not involved.)

Comment: In which way is hibernate involved (don't add useless tags)?

Comment: Why do you need to store `Age` column in `ORDERS` table ? By, the way, Do the first two rows of `ORDERS` have same `customer_id` with different `Age`s (22,32), or a misprint? Moreover, what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select c.ID, c.NAME, o.OID, c.ADDRESS, c.SALARY
from CUSTOMERS c, ORDERS o
where c.ID = o.CUSTOMER_ID 
AND c.AGE = o.Age
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT cust.id,
       cust.name,
       ordr.oid,
       cust.address,
       cust.salary
FROM   customers cust
JOIN   orders    ordr
  ON   cust.id = ordr.customer_id
 AND   cust.age = ordr.age;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on primary key and Age col as there are multiple records.

```
SELECT
    c.ID, 
    c.NAME, 
    o.OID, 
    c.ADDRESS, 
    c.SALARY
    from CUSTOMERS c
    JOIN ORDERS o ON c.ID = o.CUSTOMER_ID 
    AND c.AGE = o.Age
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This using LEFT JOIN,

```
SELECT c.id,c.name,o.oid,c.address,c.salary
FROM customers as c 
LEFT JOIN ORDERS as o ON o.customer_id=c.id AND o.age=c.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select  Customers.Id, 
    Customers.Name, 
    Orders.Oid, 
    Customers.Address, 
    Customers.Salary
From Customers
Join Orders  On 
    Customers.Id = Orders.Customer_Id And 
    Customers.Age = Orders.Age
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.oid, a.address, a.salary
FROM CUSTOMERS a
LEFT JOIN ORDERS b on a.age = b.age
WHERE a.id = '3'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Just join primary key of Customer table "ID" with foreign key ORDER table "CUSTOMER_ID"

```
select C.ID, C.NAME, O.OID, C.ADDRESS, C.SALARY
from CUSTOMER C,
     ORDERS O
where C.ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You should join on age as well

Comment: Why guess foreign and primary keys? And why even mention it? They are there to ensure data consistency.

Comment: @jarlh: The names of your columns suggest they are primary/foreign keys. Anyway, it seems an order is uniquely identified by the customer id and its age. Everybody came up with more or less the same solution.

Comment: Why bother guessing/mention pk/fk? It's a select, not insert or update.

Comment: @jarlh You want to select the order corresponding to a specific customer, so you need to join these tables. There's no specific need for the pk/fk. It's just that everybody guessed them because of the column names. You might specify the table definitions in order to avoid misunderstandings.